# How to make iOS 8 shadow darker?

Tags: ios, xcode, shadow

I have used an iOS 8 shadow property, and it's not dark enough. Here is my code:

```
View.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
View.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
View.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0f;
View.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
```

I need to make the shadow darker, so that it's almost black. And, is there a way to create a shadow or override the default property programmatically?

Comment: Try black instead of dark gray color.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to make it darker? Still too bright for me.

Comment: Make the radius smaller or duplicate the label.

Comment: This is a uiimage. So I just add another uiimage on top of it? Is there any sample code that I can know how it works?

Comment: If that uiimage is not transparent, add a UIView behind the UIImage. Add the same shadow to that too. When shadows combine, it will be darker.

Comment: Oh!! I think it will work. One more thing, how to put another image on top of the same image? Just write the same code twice?

Comment: Yes, but do not put another image. put a regular empty UIView. Otherwise you will waste the memory.

Comment: How to add same shadows to the new UIView?Any method?

Comment: it is exactly the same with what you are already doing. But add the view before uiview so image will stay in the foreground.